# Creating a new search provider in prestashop

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I have a new controller which is to list products just like a category/supplier or any other controllers in controllers/front/listing folder. I created the controller in override/controllers/front/listing I tried pasting one of the existing controller code and it worked but when I need to try my own logic it seems like I need to create a provider as the new controller is entirely for a filtered result entirely based on a table from an external module. Is it okay to create a search provider in adapter folder for the new requirement or is there an alternative. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you check the official documentation ? You should find what you are looking for here: https://devdocs.prestashop-project.org/1.7/development/components/grid/tutorials/work-with-search-form/#custom-search-controller